# Command Line - GitHub Repo Error: Does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github, push, remote-repository

Have staged and committed local repo and created remote repo. Checked to see that it does exist (`git remote -v`) and it appears to be there.

When I try to push to it with - `git push -u origin master` - I get the following error message:

```
'https//:github.com/{username}/CodingDojo_Portfolio.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Have also tried to push as from an existing repo with this:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/{username}/CodingDojo_Porfolio.git
git push -u origin master
```

I don't understand what I am doing incorrectly

(I encountered a similar error previously and I deleted the remote repo and recreated it with out the README.md and that worked, but not this time)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a weird `:` in the domain name right after the `https://`. Use `git remote set-url origin 'https//github.com/{username}/CodingDojo_Portfolio.git` to fix.

Comment: hmm true, but that is the text I copy/pasted from the error message in GitBash

Comment: any thoughts on how I might be creating that kind of response? I thought I was following to the letter, but maybe it's something I failed to do on the GitHub side (rather than my local git bash side)

Comment: Thanks for looking in to it. I think it may have been a combination of local issues. I deleted the repo and started over (again :) ) and it worked with the same procedure, after I rebooted my computer and refreshed my internet connection

Comment: At some point you'll want to learn to fix a broken repo over starting every time...